# C++ Recursive Union, Intersection, and Difference

Tags: c++, recursion, set-theory

This is a homework assignment, and I don't really know how to do this. I would normally create v3 = v1, then increment through v2, via i, and check if v2's elements are in v3. If not, I would add them to v3. But I can't create v3 outside of the method and if I try to create it inside the method, it would just reset itself. Can anyone help me please?

Here is the code I have for them and their wrapper functions thus far (it's just the skeleton):

```
// returns a new vector; every element in v1 and every element in v2 are also in this new vector
// if an element appears in both v1 and v2, it is only added once to the new vector
template <typename T> vector<T> vec_union(vector<T> &v1, vector<T> &v2)
{
    return v1;
}

template <typename T> vector<T> vec_union(vector<T> &v1, vector<T> &v2, unsigned i)
{
    return v1;
}

// returns a new vector; every element that is in both v1 and v2 are also in this new vector
// there are no duplicates in v1 and v2
template <typename T> vector<T> intersection(vector<T> v1, vector<T> v2)
{
    return v1;
}

template <typename T> vector<T> intersection(vector<T> v1, vector<T> v2, unsigned i)
{
    return v1;
}

// returns a new vector; every element that is in v1 but not v2 are also in this new vector
// there are no duplicates in v1 and v2
template <typename T> vector<T> difference(vector<T> v1, vector<T> v2)
{
    return v1;
}


template <typename T> vector<T> difference(vector<T> v1, vector<T> v2, unsigned i)
{
    return v1;
}
```

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: @Jaysen Stoudt you didn't post your entire code. All we have are the wrappers. Please edit your question so we can answer.

Comment: @jrd1 My question is how can I implement it since I can't create v3 outside of the method and I don't know how to create it inside the method?

Comment: you need us to write body for those all functions???

Comment: @Zadirion The first of each pair are the wrappers, the second is the method, I don't know where to start since I don't know how to create v3 in it.

Comment: @555k I just need to know how to create v3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create `v3` by fowarding the `T` template parameter and passing it to `vector` like I have done below:

```
vector<T> v3;
```

I have implemented your `vec_union` function for you. Note the following:
I have created `v3` inside the function.
I have returned `v3`, which results in a copy of `v3` which the outside code will get, when the caller calls `vec_union`.

```
template <typename T> vector<T> 
vec_union(vector<T> &v1, vector<T> &v2)
{
  if ( v2.empty() )
    return v1;

  vector<T>::iterator found = std::find(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.back());
  if ( found == v1.end() )
  {
    // all good, element not already in v1, so insert it.
    T value = v2.back();
    v1.push_back(value);
    v2.pop_back(); // remove back element
    return vec_union(v1, v2);
  }
  else
  {
    // element was already in v1, skip it and call vec_union again
    v2.pop_back(); // remove back element
    return vec_union(v1, v2);
  }
}
```

Note that my answer modifies v1 and v2. I assumed this is what your teacher expected in order to achieve a recursive implementation that isn't ridiculously inefficient by repeatedly copying v1 and v2 around.

You call vec_union like so:

```
vector<int> firstVector;
vector<int> secondVector;
vector<int> unionVector = vec_union(firstVector, secondVector);
```

Comment: My first concern is that this isn't recursive. How could I turn this into a recursive function? 

Also, in this, does it add every value from v2 to v3? Resulting in possible duplicates? And if so, how can I avoid that?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice those requirements.Let me fix it for you

Comment: When doing this, does it affect the original vectors? Like, would the original v2 be empty?

Comment: EDIT: Just read the note. Yeah, in the tester class, he reuses the vectors to test again, which is why in my original plans, I was going to create a v3. How can I modify this so that I don't change the original v1 and v2?

Comment: You can move the code from vec_union to a new vec_union_helper function, call it from vec_union and pass it copies of v1 and v2. The originals remain unchanged, and everything should work ok.

Comment: So for example, in my wrapper functions, I could put:
vector<T> vec1 = v1;
vector<T> vec2 = v2:
return vec_union(vec1, vec2); //the recursive function

Then use the code you provided, or a modification of it, and I will only be changing the copied vectors? The v1 and v2 would remain intact as they should be?

Comment: The function you wrote checks if v2 is empty, but what if v1 is empty, or both are empty? Do I need to write checks for each scenario?

Comment: The function you wrote checks if v2 is empty, but what if v1 is empty, or both are empty? Do I need to write checks for each scenario?

Comment: nope. The recursive algorithm consumes elements from `v2` one by one.  The condition you are referring to is the end condition for the recursion. i.e  When there are no more elements in `v2`, stop recursion